# `require': cannot load such file -- mime/message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, mime

I am trying to run a program to import mails from gmail. When I run the ruby fine it returns an error

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require': cannot load such file -- mime/message (LoadError)
```

Can someone guide me to resolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

when you run `gem install gmail`
installed not worked gem

I fix this issue installed last gmail gem from github

`git clone git://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail.git`
`cd gmail`
`bundle install`
`rake install`

Or if you're using bundler, change your Gemfile entry to:
`gem 'gmail', :git => 'git://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail.git'`

Answer (score -1):

removing require 'mime' in my ruby file resolved the issue.

Thanks!